# Microcontroller writes additional data on high-frequent writes

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, communication, rs232

I'm using [C-Control](http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http://www.c-control.de&langpair=de%7Cen&hl=de&ie=UTF-8) Pro 128 which contains a atmega processor. I've connected the rs232 interface with my PC and read the incoming data, having the following program executed on the controller:

```
void main(void) {
  Serial_Init(0, SR_8BIT | SR_1STOP | SR_EVEN_PAR, SR_BD9600);
  Serial_Write(0, 1);
  Serial_Write(0, 2);
}
```

I'd expected the controller to output the bytes *1* and *2*. Instead, I receive the following:

```
1
2
119
119
```

If I write e.g. eight bytes instead of two, *119* is appended eight times to the actual data. If I write only one byte, only the one byte is transmitted, so all works correct.

The number *119* is independend from the value of the bytes and from the baud rate.

If I add a *sleep* instruction between the *write* commands (about 50ms), the problem does not occur.

Has anyone had a similar problem or any idea where the problem could be located?

Comment: When you write 8 bytes, do those 8 bytes arrive at the PC correctly, then you receive 8x 119 ?

Comment: Yes, first the whole correct block, then the 8x119.

Comment: Do you have a logic analyser or an oscilloscope ?

Comment: Ok, I'll look at the oscilloscope graph.

Comment: Just send one byte, preferably something with a distinctive pattern, like [the letter K](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Rs232_oscilloscope_trace.svg/160px-Rs232_oscilloscope_trace.svg.png)

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, this solved my problem! The oscilloscope showed the data exactly as expected, and so I've used a different terminal program, which does not show the additional bytes. The problem must be in the terminal program I used first. Kinda strange, because I never discovered any problem with that, until now. Anyway, no problem left. If you want me to accept your answer, just post the last comment as an answer :)

Comment: FYI: let us know your previous configurations , I think you have turned on XON OFF mode.Where it sends the control characters through the data channel.

Comment: No, Xon Xoff was not enabled, it does not even make any difference in the first terminal. I used 9600 baud, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit and even parity, which is also the configuration in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to diagnose these sorts of problems is to cut them in half. Whose fault is this? The C-Control or the PC? If we can look at the actual data sent on the wire, we can tell whereabouts the fault lies.

Start by sending a simple, easily identifiable character, over and over again. I like to use the one used as an example on the [Wikipedia's RS232 page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) because you can easily see what the waveform is supposed to look like.

[image: K RS232]

Now you'll need an oscilloscope. If you can't afford one, I highly recommend the [Saleae Logic](http://www.saleae.com/logic/) analyser. It's not that expensive, and it will save you literally days off your life. Look at the waveform on the bus, and check that it matches the waveform you expct. Check for any rogue characters transmitted afterwards.

Assuming everything looks OK, then the problem is somewhere in the PC.  If the rogue 119 characters appear, then you know the problem is in the C-Control